# Does angular $routeProvider only work with html5Mode?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, routes

I don't really understand the whole html5mode/hashbangmode business.

```
$routeProvider.when('/a/b/:c', {})
```

This only works if I set to html5mode. Why? Is html5mode supported in all browsers?

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
```

By "works" I mean I can access the route parameter will get logged.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(scope, route) {
    console.log(route.pathParams.c)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, `$routeProvider` is very flaky and it will cause you alot of wasted time and headaches.  I have tried adding the `$locationProvider` in several different ways based on things I've read on SO, and each time wierd things happen and there is always at least 1 bad thing that happens that forces me to get rid of it again. For example, sometimes the underlying `.json` calls will break because they are referencing a path that has a duplicated component, other times it will break all the paths to your images in `/assets`, other times all the routes will stop working except the 'otherwise' default route (despite the code being correct). The problem with all of the angular advice on SO and even in the docs is that they don't put the advice in the context of a specific version of angular. Too many versions, too many variations of syntaxes, too many files named differently from version to version, too many ways to install everything (grunt? npm? manually? gem? some other thing that I've never heard of but suddenly everyone seems to be using?), broken links to google hosted js libs everywhere that all the tutorials tell you to use, which all adds up to headaches and wasted time. You'd think google would have the resources to properly explain how to use this thing. Good luck with that.... If anyone wants to form a suicide pact maybe we can meet up and put a bullet in our heads together